# How to create rails_admin navigation labels without creating empty models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, navigation, dsl, rails-admin

In rails admin, you can define a navigation label to a model and its children like so:

```rb
# in rails_admin.rb

config.model Order do
  navigation_label 'Orders related'
end

config.model OrderProducts do
  parent Order
end
```

Is there a way to add labels to the navigation menu without creating models (i.e. just for grouping)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [wiki](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Navigation), you can append static links to the navigation like so:

```
RailsAdmin.config do |config|
  config.navigation_static_links = {
    'Google' => 'http://www.google.com'
  }
end
```

If you're just looking to group them, you can namespace your models under a module, and then you will see your models grouped under the module name in the navigation.  Like so: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMJs2.png

```
RailsAdmin.config do |config|
  config.model 'Spree::Product' do
    ...
  end
end
```